# Problem replacing string in RTF file - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rtf

i'm facing a problem with Rich Text Format. I need to replace some Tags with their values.
In my case i need to replace the Tag \itemNo\ with the word ITEM0003

Instead of writing ITEM0003, it writes an empty value! I tried to remove the backslashes from Tag and the result is \ITEM0003\ . So i think that the problem are backslashes

But i can't remove that, because i have hundreds of file with the same tag.

Any idea?
Here the code

```
string input = @"\itemNo\";
string value = "ITEM0003";

string pathTemplate = @"c:\temp\template\CAT.rtf";
string pathGenerazione = @"c:\temp\generated\CAT.rtf";
       
RichTextBox _rtf = new RichTextBox();
_rtf.LoadFile(pathTemplate);
_rtf.Rtf = _rtf.Rtf.Replace(input, value);  
_rtf.SaveFile(pathGenerazione);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use  `string input = @"\\itemNo\\";`.

Demo:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Output:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Does it help you?

Comment: yes, now the replace works perfectly. But unfortunately when i save the new file, rtf loses some text formatting. This is another problem, you solved the first one. Thank you